# Python Django - как реализовать добавление модулей через админку?

Tags: python, django

извините, вопрос без кода

В wordpress есть плагины, которые легко добавляются. Если ли схожее решение для django в виде модуля? или как это можно реализовать? может кто-то сталкивался. пишу crm и задача, чтобы новые модули(плагины) пользователи могли добавлять через админку.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону django cms и wagtail

Comment: там так же предлагают ручками скачивать и потом install app.

Comment: Боюсь, Django не очень рассчитано на подобный вид расширения