# call_command migrate problem python django

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь динамически добавить приложение и выполнить makemigrations и migration, но он не показывает print ('2'). Перезагружается и просит применить миграцию вручную

**some.py**

```
settings.INSTALLED_APPS += ('tests.apps.OrderConfig',)
apps.app_configs = OrderedDict()
apps.apps_ready = apps.models_ready = apps.loading = apps.ready = False
apps.clear_cache()
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
management.call_command('makemigrations','tests', interactive=False)
print('>>WORK1')
management.call_command('migrate', app_module.MODULE_NAME, interactive=False, skip_checks=True)
print('>>WORK2') #this don't show
```

**Terminal**:

```
Migrations for 'orders':
orders\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Status
- Create model Orders
>>WORK1
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: orders
Running migrations:
[11/Feb/2021 02:07:22] "GET /plugins/repository/12/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14459
C:\PythonProject\ServiceCRM3\plugins\settings_plugin.py changed, reloading.
  Applying orders.0001_initial...Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): orders.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 11, 2021 - 02:07:24
Django version 3.1.4, using settings 'ServiceCRM3.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Comment: Динамически где и как? Когда и каким образом запускается этот ваш some.py?

Comment: А вообще запускайте runserver с опцией `--noreload` чтобы не перезапускался

Comment: (а вообще я уже [высказывался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240176/python-django-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83#comment2176409_1240176) что Django не очень рассчитано на подобный вид расширения...)

Comment: спасибо, noreload  помогло, так как migrate записал в базу migrаtions данные. У меня такая задача: добавлять плагины через админку. Я решил это так. Создается отдельно app, потом оно просто распаковывается в корень app, потом прописываются в файл новые urls и install_apps, выполняются миграции. Тоесть  делаю динамически, но добавляенное приложение после перезагрузки сервера остается навсегда.

Comment: в любом случае noreload и потом migrate подвисает приложение и надо перезагружать страницу в ручную. решил просто делать ссылку с логикой на новое окно, где его  можно просто закрыт. даже если оно крашанется.